# Regex check if the string represents 5 or 6 digit number

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need to check if the given string represents 5 or 6 digits number, then print 'yes', otherwise 'no'. The number should not contain leading zeros, for example:

> 012345 ----- // no

> 0123456 ---- // no

> 12345 ----- // yes

I'm using Python3. For now I know that my regex should be like this:

```
re.search('\d{5,6}')
```

But it fits only for numbers without 0 at the beginning. Do you know how to solve that problem?

Comment: How about `\b[1-9]\d{4,5}\b`?

Comment: @jdaz Maybe `4,5` if the first digit is already non-zero?

Comment: @tadman yes, updated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this: `^[1-9]\d{4,5}$`

Explanation:

- `^` start at the beginning of the string
- `[1-9]` the first character must be a number between 1 and 9
- `\d{4,5}` match an additional 4 or 5 characters that must be digits
- `$` until the end of the string

Comment: Works, thanks a lot